# In-app ошибка

Tags: in-app-purchases, android, java

Приветствую!
Занимаюсь in-app'ом первый раз, не судите строго :)
Выложил в гугл-плей альфа\бета версию freemium-приложение. НЕ опубликовывал. Создал группу, чтобы можно было тестировать приложение бесплатно. Добавил из гугловских библиотек vending и `trivialdrivesample.util`. В `Main` прописываю:

```
// Донат
static final String SKU_DONATE = "money"; 
// Код для обратного вызова 
private int REQUEST_CODE = 10001;        
// Экземпляр класса для работы с магазином 
IabHelper mHelper; 
Context context = this;
 .....................................................

 String base64EncodedPublicKey = "keyFromGoogle";
            mHelper = new IabHelper(context, base64EncodedPublicKey);
            mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);
            mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                        if (!result.isSuccess()) 
                        {                       
                            // Произошла ошибка авторизации библиотеки                  
                            return; 
                        }   
                    }           
            });

             final IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase info) 
                {
                    if (result.isFailure()) 
                     {                 
                         // Обработка произошедшей ошибки покупки 
                         return;             
                     }              
                     if (info.getSku().equals(SKU_DONATE)) 
                     {       
                         // Говорим пользователю спасибо за перечисление средств   
                         return;
                     }                  
                }    
             }; 
             mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_DONATE, REQUEST_CODE, mPurchaseFinishedListener);

  ...................................................................................

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) 
    {             
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);       
    } 
}
```

Выкидывает

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: IAB
> helper is not set up. Can't perform
> operation: launchPurchaseFlow

Что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не дожидаетесь окончания инициализации `IabHelper`. `launchPurchaseFlow()` стоит делать тогда, когда произойдёт `IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener.onIabSetupFinished()`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Получилось )))
Если не сложно - объясните как тестирование сделать? Как и написал до этого - создал группу в гугле, сделал "альфа-версию(черновик)", добавил группу в тестировщики, но по ссылке https://play.google.com/apps/testing/myproject так приложение и не отобразилось, хотя прошло уже много времени (да и в самой группе не отобразилось что им дали доступ).. В чем может быть ошибка?
P.S. приложение ни разу не опубликовывал и в нем содержатся не все данные для публикации (нет картинки, описания)

Comment: По этой ссылке приложения не будет. Там вы просто указываете что будете пользоваться тестовой версией. После этого вам прилетает обновление программы до тестовой версии из маркета, т.е. приложение по всей видимости надо сперва опубликовать и поставить из маркета.